# set my own message in the alertView of calendar events

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, calendar

I'm currently using the `EKEvent` and `EKEevntUI` frameworks,
My Question is : is it possible to set my own message in the `UIAlertView` for calendar events??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
//set event reminder
//make sure to import EventKit framework

    EKEventStore *eventDB = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init]autorelease];
    EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];
    NSString * eventTitle = @"This is your custom title";
    myEvent.title = eventTitle;



//set event time frame (1 hour) the "initWithTimeInterval" is where we account for the users timezone by adding the correctedTime from GMT to the calendar time ( so its not off by hours when entering into calendar)
    myEvent.startDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:correctedTimeForCalendarEvent sinceDate:destinationDate ]autorelease];
    myEvent.endDate   = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:3600 sinceDate:myEvent.startDate]autorelease];
    myEvent.allDay = NO;

//set event reminders 1 day and 1 hour before
    myAlarmsArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    EKAlarm *alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600]; // 1 Hour
    EKAlarm *alarm2 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-86400]; // 1 Day
    [myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm1];
    [myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm2];
    myEvent.alarms = myAlarmsArray;



    [myEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    NSError *err;

    [eventDB saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 

    if (err == noErr) {
        //no error, but do not show alert because we do that below.
    }
```

Comment: using the code above you can set your own title, which will show as the description on the Calendar.

Comment: p.s. this was a snippet of code I pulled from my project and pasted, there might be some stuff that doesnt apply to you here.

Comment: thanks Louie ! but what I am talking about is the alertView that appears to notify the user about the event ! this alertView contain two buttons the first one "close" and the second one "view event", in case I want to change the message that appears in this alertView :(

Comment: oh ok, your talking about a Local Notification. Take a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381379/local-notification-on-arrival-iphone-sdk